# Select clause null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am currently using

```
your = from p in (toSelect)
select new
{
  last = p.Last,
  current = p.CurrentPlayer,
  seats = from s in (p.Seated)
  select new
  {
      UID = s.UID,
      buyin = s.BuyIn
  }
}
```

`p.Seated` is an array, how can I pass `null` every time `s.UID` is unset? I know about "`where`" but I was to know which seats are free (e.g. `null`)

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: what does *unset* mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass `null`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
your = from p in (toSelect)
select new
{
  last = p.Last,
  current = p.CurrentPlayer,
  seats = p.Seated.Select(s => s.UID != null
    ? new
      {
          UID = s.UID,
          buyin = s.BuyIn
      }
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your expression that you're assigning to `seats` with:

```
seats = p.Seated.Select(s => s != null ? new { UID = s.UID, buyin = s.BuyIn } : null)
```

> Hope this is clear enough.

I'll be honest. It's not clear enough. Is `s.UID` a nullable type and that's what we need to compare to `null`?